# Develop Plugin for web browser using java for chrome

Tags: java, javascript, jquery-plugins

I am looking for developing a plugin (that should able to access the current web page's content that displayed in the browser).
The browser could be chrome or mozilla.
Could someone assist me with the language that can be used for develop? and provide me the way to start develop.
It would be helpful if someone could provide the sample?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: plugin mechanisms are vendor specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Javascript to do this in Chrome. Follow the API link below to get hold of the content in the current tab. You can also inject your own javascript into the tab.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/tabs.html

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/content_scripts.html

Comment: Hi the above link is really helpful. Thanks. I want this plugin (javacript definitions) to be common for all web pages. When browser starts, this plugin should executed irrespective of what page it displays in broswer. Provide me suggestions